# SQL calculations based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `transactions`:

```
client_id   Amount   payment ref   contract type
1           300      MTV           1
1           300      MTV           1
1           300      MTV           1
1           150      ML            1
2           150      ML            2
2           150      ML            2
2           150      ML            2
2           150      ML            2
```

If a client is on contract 1, then their total payments should be 3 x MTV(300) and 3 x ML(150). If they are on contract 2, then they pay 6 x ML(150).

I am trying to figure out how to get the total number of payments remaining for each client based on their contract type. For example client_id = 1:

```
client_id   type   Total Paid   Payments remaining
1           MTV    900          0
1           ML     150          2
```

I can do the first three columns using this:

```
SELECT   `client_id`,
         `payment ref` AS `type`,
         SUM(`Amount`) as `Total Paid` 
FROM     transactions
WHERE    client_id = 1
GROUP BY type;
```

How do I add on the payments remaining column?

```
CASE WHEN `contract type` = 1 THEN (3 - COUNT(MTV)... ?
```

Comment: How do you know, what contract a client has?

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close, there was an issue with the GROUP BY clause not including client_id and payment ref:

```
SELECT 
client_id, 
payment ref AS type, 
SUM(Amount) as 'Total Paid',
CASE 
WHEN contract type = 1 THEN (3 - COUNT(*))
WHEN contract type = 2 THEN (6 -  COUNT(*))
END as 'Payments remaining'
FROM transactions 
WHERE client_id = 1 
GROUP BY client_id, 
payment ref;
```

Answer (score 1):

could use case when and group by

```
  select 
      client_id
      , payment
      , case 
          when `contract type` = 1 and `payment ref` = 'MTV' then  3*300 
          when `contract type` = 1 and `payment ref` = 'ML' then  3*150
          when  `contract type` = 2 then 3*150 
        end as  to_pay
      , sum(Amount) payed
      , case 
          when `contract type` = 1 and `payment ref` = 'MTV' then  3*300/SUM(Amount) 
          when `contract type` = 1 and `payment ref` = 'ML' then  3*150/sum(Amount)
          when  `contract type` = 2 then 3*150 / sum(Amount)
        end number_of
        end as  `Payments remaining`
  from my_table 
  group by client_id, `contract type`, `payment ref`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query

```
    select *
       ,case contract_type 
            when 1 then 3-paidCount  
            when 2 then 6-paidCount  
       End               
    from (
        select client_id  , payment_ref ,  contract_type,sum(Amount)TotalPaid ,count(*) paidCount
        FROM     transactions
        group by client_id  , payment_ref ,  contract_type
      ) t
```